# "Slide to unlock" text animation on Android, looking like in iOS

Tags: android, android-animation

Is there a way to do the "slide to unlock" text animation on Android, looking like iOS animation?

Comment: Have you ever succeeded in what you were trying to accomplish? I'm currently trying to do the same—is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to create animations on android.

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: This is helpful for learning how to animate things, such as text views, but mimicking the animation used on the iPhone is a much larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real answer for this question:

https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android

Information on how to use it is in the wiki.

**But for the sake of completion:**

Add a ShimmerTextView to your layout:

```
<com.romainpiel.shimmer.ShimmerTextView
    android:id="@+id/shimmer_tv"
    android:text="@string/shimmer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#444"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>
```

To start the animation:

```
shimmer = new Shimmer();
shimmer.start(myShimmerTextView);
```

You may want to keep track of the shimmer instance after the animation is started if you want to stop it.

To stop it:

```
shimmer.cancel();
```